# AWS Quicksight - Update filter value based on another filter's input (category and sub-category)

Tags: filter, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

I have a table that has category and subcategory, among other columns

| Category | Subcategory | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | stuff |
| A | 2 | stuff |
| A | 3 | stuff |
| B | 1 | stuff |
| B | 4 | stuff |
| C | 3 | stuff |

Currently, when I set a filter for both columns, and I filter a category (say Category="B") the filters aren't affecting each other, so the filter offers all the available values (1,2,3,4).

I want the subcategory filter's available values to narrow down to B's subcategory values (1,4).

Any way to achieve the behavior I describe here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!
As with most things Quicksight, it's there, but not that intuitive.
When you have 2 (or more) filters, that are not based on calculated fields, you can enter the settings of the filter you want to adjust (subcategory in the example above) pick edit from the menu and then choose "show relevant values only".
It then asks you to determine by which filter should values be updated (category in the example above).
Pick the right column, and you're done.